# Is $\mathbb{Q}(0) = \mathbb{Q}(1)?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I know $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt 2)=\{ a+b \sqrt 2\mid  a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

My question is   about $\mathbb{Q}(0)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(1)$

Is $\mathbb{Q}(0) = \mathbb{Q}(1)?$

**My thinking** :

$\mathbb{Q} (0)=\{ a+b \sqrt 0\mid  a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}=\{ a\mid  a \in \mathbb{Q}\}=\mathbb{Q}$

$\mathbb{Q} (1)=\{ a+b \sqrt 1\mid  a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}=\{ a+b\mid  a , b\in \mathbb{Q}\}=\mathbb{Q}$

Therefore $\mathbb{Q}(0) = \mathbb{Q}(1)$

Comment: The conclusion is correct but I’m not sure your definition is. For any algebraic number $x$, $\mathbb{Q}(x)=\{P(x),\, P \in \mathbb{Q}[T]\}$. So in particular $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(x)$ (constant polynomials) and if $x$ is rational $\mathbb{Q} \supset \mathbb{Q}(x)$ (a polynomial with rational coefficients taken at a rational point is rational).

Comment: Both ${0 \in \mathbb{Q}}$ and ${1 \in \mathbb{Q}}$... ${\mathbb{Q}(a)}$ is meant to represent the smallest field containing both ${\mathbb{Q}}$ and $a$. Clearly, if ${a \in \mathbb{Q}}$ - then ${\mathbb{Q}(a)=\mathbb{Q}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in @Riemann'sPointyNose's comment, the *intent* of notations $k(\alpha)$ for field $k$ and $\alpha$ (somewhere?!?) satisfying a (non-constant) polynomial equation with coefficients in $k$, is that it is a/the smallest field (where!?!) containing $k$ and containing $\alpha$.

Likewise, as in @Mindlack's comment, for such $k$ and $\alpha$, it will turn out that all the elements of $k(\alpha)$ (when we figure out a good definition) will actually be *polynomials* in $\alpha$, with coefficients in $k$.

The questioner's cases of $\alpha=0,1$ are a bit extreme, and we have a burden of toooo much side-channel information, so it is possibly worthwhile to review things calmly. :)  Already 150 years ago Kronecker had misgivings about "adjoining" $\alpha$'s to fields $k$, insofar as there is/was an element of circularity... assuming that $\alpha$ is "somewhere out there in a larger field (containing $k$)".

So, as is absolutely usual nowadays, once we know the intention, and are aware of some of these potential problems, the issue/construction is usefully reframed. Given field $k$ and irreducible (non-constant) polynomial $P(x)\in k[x]$, we can create a field extension $K$ of $k$ in which $P(x)=0$ has a root $\alpha$. Kronecker's idea was to "create" $K$ as a quotient $K=k[x]/\langle P(x)\rangle$, of the polynomial ring by the ideal generated by $P(x)$. Then (as usual) we can prove that the *image* $\alpha$ of $x$ in $K$ is a root of $P(x)=0$.

This is either philosophically relieving or disappointing, depending on whether one was mainly worried about *assuming* roots were "out there", or, one hoped to *find* roots of polynomial equations "out there".

Another option, somewhat pre-Kronecker, was to use the complex numbers (approximately known to be algebraically closed since Gauss, 1800+/-) in which to "find" roots of polynomials with rational (or real, or complex) coefficients. If one "believes in" complex numbers, one way or another, this is reassuring about roots of polynomial equations having some sort of a-priori existence "out there"... So would/might lead us to think that $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is completely unambiguous: take a/the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ containing $\mathbb Q$ and $\alpha$. And, indeed, if $\alpha$ is unambiguously specified as a complex number, this is fine. However, unambiguous specification of a complex root of a polynomial equation is non-trivial for high-degree polynomials, and already ambiguous for quadratic ones. E.g., for $P(x)=x^2+1$, which $\sqrt{-1}$ do we take? Since they only differ by $\pm$, the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-1})$ is the same either way.

A somewhat trickier example is about cube roots of positive (non-cube) integers. There is a *real* cube root, and two complex-conjugate cube roots. So even the fields themselves will differ...

Returning to the questioner's example: Kronecker's approach gives $\mathbb Q$ in both cases, as does the imbed-in-the-complex-numbers approach.

Comment: +1 for giving both perspectives of an algebraic number : as a complex number and the view of Kronecker.